# PHP 'For Each' Insert rows into mysql from array or string

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert multiple rows into a table based on the array...with each $value being each of the comma separated values.

I know this is NOT the best way or even correct way to do this - just trying to get some guidance on how to achieve this the right way.

```
$someArray=array(96,97,98,99,100,101,103,105);
foreach($someArray as $value){ 

$sql = "INSERT INTO bid_package(user_company) VALUES('".$value."');";
echo $sql;
echo "<br />";


 INSERT INTO bid_package(user_company) VALUES('96');
 INSERT INTO bid_package(user_company) VALUES('97');
 INSERT INTO bid_package(user_company) VALUES('98');
 INSERT INTO bid_package(user_company) VALUES('99');
 INSERT INTO bid_package(user_company) VALUES('100');
 INSERT INTO bid_package(user_company) VALUES('101');
 INSERT INTO bid_package(user_company) VALUES('103');
 INSERT INTO bid_package(user_company) VALUES('105');
```

Comment: How are you planning to execute the query? I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Which are you using, `mysqli` or `PDO`?

Comment: Are you asking to do this the "right" way, or why your existing code doesn't work, or...something else?

Comment: You aren't executing _any_ sql in your code.

Comment: I am using mysqli

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple lists of values in a single `INSERT`:

```
$values = implode(', ', array_map(function($val) {
    return "($val)";
    }, $someArray));
$sql = "INSERT INTO bid_package (user_company) VALUES $values;";
```

This will create a query that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO bid_package (user_company) VALUES (96), (97), (98), (99), (100), (101), (103), (105);
```

If you were using PDO, it would be better to use a prepared statement, to prevent SQL-injection.

```
$values = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($someArray), "(?)"))
$sql = "INSERT INTO bid_package (user_company) VALUES $values;"
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($someArray);
```

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica The first version isn't, the second is. But if the array is not user-generated data, I don't consider it a significant problem.

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica Unfortunately, doing it safely in mysqli is difficult because `mysqli_bind_param()` requires references.

Comment: Yours is fine because you don't try to combine them all into a single statement. Note that you only need to call `bind_param()` once, before the loop, since it binds to a reference.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be using prepared statements instead of inserting the variable directly into the query. Here is one way of doing what you are attempting.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'mysampledb'); // your mysqli handle

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO SampleTable VALUES (?)"); // prepare your query

//bind value as a reference
$stmt->bind_param('s', $val);

//define values
$someArray=array(96,97,98,99,100,101,103,105);

//loop through values
foreach($someArray as $val) {
    //execute statement
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

If you are ever passing data to a query, you should use prepared statements.